# How to integrate 'npm install' into ASP.NET CORE 2.1 Docker build

Tags: docker, npm, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I have not found a way to build a ASP.NET Core 2.1 Docker image while doing a proper `npm install` during the build process.

My `Dockerfile` looks like this (one that has been generated from Visual Studio):

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY --from=frontend . .
COPY ["myProject.WebUi/myProject.WebUi.csproj", "myProject.WebUi/"]
COPY ["myProject.SearchIndex/myProject.SearchIndex.csproj", "myProject.SearchIndex/"]
COPY ["myProject.SearchIndex.Common/myProject.SearchIndex.Common.csproj", "myProject.SearchIndex.Common/"]

RUN dotnet restore "myProject.WebUi/myProject.WebUi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/myProject.WebUi"
RUN dotnet build "myProject.WebUi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "myProject.WebUi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myProject.WebUi.dll"]
```

In the previous images from Microsoft (e.g. aspnetcore-build:2.0) were third-party tools provided, such as npm, yarn, bower, pip, ...)

At the moment I do a local `npm install` in the project folder. But for automatic building like it is offered from Docker Hub or Azure Container Registry the note modules are missing.

Comment: I would add `RUN npm install` after `WORKDIR "/src/myProject.WebUi"`. In case there is no `npm` in the base image, then also add `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs` before it.

Comment: @qbik Thanks, I guess your suggestion goes into the right direction. But installing nodejs does not install npm. And something like `apt-get install npm` is not available.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY --from=frontend . .
COPY ["myProject.WebUi/myProject.WebUi.csproj", "myProject.WebUi/"]
COPY ["myProject.SearchIndex/myProject.SearchIndex.csproj", "myProject.SearchIndex/"]
COPY ["myProject.SearchIndex.Common/myProject.SearchIndex.Common.csproj", "myProject.SearchIndex.Common/"]

RUN dotnet restore "myProject.WebUi/myProject.WebUi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/myProject.WebUi"
RUN apt-get update -yq && apt-get upgrade -yq && apt-get install -yq curl git nano
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential
RUN npm install -g npm
RUN npm install
RUN dotnet build "myProject.WebUi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "myProject.WebUi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myProject.WebUi.dll"]
```

Comment: it seems that the default `nodejs` apt package for Debian 9 (stretch) does not include `npm`. Node has a [detailed instruction for installing](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) on dofferent OSes.

Comment: @qbik How can the same task be solved for windows containers?

Answer (score 23):

## Update for ASP.NET Core 3.0 Web App with SPA

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# Prevent 'Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)'
ENV APT_KEY_DONT_WARN_ON_DANGEROUS_USAGE=1

# install NodeJS 13.x
# see https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#deb
RUN apt-get update -yq 
RUN apt-get install curl gnupg -yq 
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY MyApplication/*.csproj ./MyApplication/
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY MyApplication/. ./MyApplication/
WORKDIR /app/MyApplication
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/MyApplication/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApplication.dll"]
```

Then

```
docker build --pull -t MyApplication
docker run --name myapp --rm -it -p 8000:80 MyApplication
```

The app will be available at `localhost:8000`.

Comment: You're the best. Thanks a million, I've been trying to get this running all day!

Comment: I could be wrong, since I'm just now learning about Docker, but it appears that the ENV line has two ENVs, when it should only have one?

Comment: Thanks Shaun! Such a coincidence that I was looking for this issue and found your answer (remember me from LT?).

Question: Given that Docker caches each layer, do you know if changes to package.json will get reflected in the container (i.e. node_modules/ folder added/updated/removed accordingly) without having to purge the layer cache?

Comment: Coincidence indeed @ablopez, and I'm afraid I don't know the answer to your follow up question.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I needed to have a docker image running a nodeJS project which is able to execute script like "dotnet xxx.xxx.dll".

I was struggling trying to fix "dotnet command not found" inside my docker.

I succeeded to fix it easily by adding at the beginning of my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:alpine AS node_base
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
COPY --from=node_base . .

RUN echo "NODE Version:" && node --version
RUN echo "NPM Version:" && npm --version
RUN echo "dotnet Version:" &&  dotnet --version
```

(you can adjust versions accordingly)

I took inspiration from this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12959).

Hope this trick can help you too :)

Comment: Running the line `COPY --from=node_base . .`  gives the following error `cannot copy to non-directory: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cxre60io3tls1hmjs5xpgd6iy/merged/var/lock`. What could be wrong?

Comment: @M.Azyoksul For me it worked, when I replaced `node:alpine` with `node:latest` (BTW: it is the image used in referenced issue, not the alpine version)