# The command 'dotnet' not found in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, .net-core

I trie to build an image with docker to run a project, but When i run docker build, the step 5/12:

**/bin/sh: 1: dotnet: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 127**

Note: I'm running .Net Core and Node Modules, so i put all in the Dockerfile, is that OK? I'm new with Docker

This is my dockerfile:

```
# Otenemos el SDK de .Net Core en la versión 2.1
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
FROM node:11
WORKDIR /FrontEnd

#Copiamos el archivo .csproj y restauramos paquetes.
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install

# Copiamos todo lo demás
COPY . ./

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /FrontEnd

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "run" ]
```

**EDIT**

This is my new Dockerfile
Seems working in console, but in Chrome doesn't.

This is the command that i run in console:
docker run --rm name_proj:latest

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /FrontEnd
COPY *.csproj ./
COPY package.json ./
RUN dotnet restore
RUN apt-get update -yq && apt-get upgrade -yq && apt-get install -yq curl git nano
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential
RUN npm install -g npm
RUN npm install
COPY . ./

#FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "run" ]
```

The log in console:
[image]

When i open localhost:5001 is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can only inherit from one container via `FROM`. Every time you use a `FROM`, you are switching to using a new container as the base. When you do

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
FROM node:11
```

The effect is the same as just

```
FROM node:11
```

And in the `node` contianer, there's no .NET Core installed.

If you want a contianer where both `dotnet` and `npm` commands are available, you need to build it yourself. Here's an answer on stackoverflow that shows you how do to that: [How to integrate 'npm install' into ASP.NET CORE 2.1 Docker build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918919/how-to-integrate-npm-install-into-asp-net-core-2-1-docker-build). The short version is that you start from one container (maybe `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk`) and you install the `node` packages into it manually.

Comment: thank you, I updated the post, please, It would be a good idea if you can see it

Comment: You need to connect the network ports inside the container (5000, 5001) to outside the container. If you are using the command line, that's adding `-p 5000:5000` in your `docker run` invocation. That maps the port number 5000 from inside the container to port 5000 outside the container (aka localhost). Then you should be able to access it via your browser.

Comment: is not working with docker run --rm -p 5000:5000 name_proj:latest
The http 5000 says EMPTY_RESPONSE and https 5001 says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED...

Comment: That sounds like a bug in your application. Try with a empty asp.net core project just to be sure.

Comment: The same error, with new mvc proj, i tried with --expose but nothing happens

Comment: I use `.UseUrls("https://+:5001");` in the Program.cs and add `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5001` in Dockerfile...  it works, but in console print https://[::]:5001... Do you know why?