# Does mcr.microsoft.com support ASP.NET Core version 2?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, jenkins

Ever since Microsoft updated docker in August from `FROM microsoft/` to `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/`, my docker file is not built using Jenkins.

```
// this is what edited docker file looks like
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:2.1 AS build

...

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:2.1
```

I followed [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-developer-community-blog/deprecating-the-distribution-of-microsoft-container-images-via/ba-p/2366861) to update my docker file.

However this solution also occurs the error when I build docker in Jenkins.

> Step 1/10 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/aspnetcore-build:2 AS build
> manifest for mcr.microsoft.com/aspnetcore-build:2 not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by "2" is not found

Probably because ASP.NET Core version 2 does not exist in updated Docker hub I guess?

While I was searching to solve this problem, I found [this article](https://dev.to/luizhlelis/net-core-2-1-container-images-were-deleted-from-docker-hub-3nhm)

Do I have to update my ASP.NET Core version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aspnetcore-build` had the sdk needed to build ASP.Net Core applications, this should be rougly the same as `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:2.1` so you could try that image. For the runtime you could use `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:2.1`.

But you really should update your application as well, 2.0 has been end of life for a long time already and even 2.1 (which was a LTS release) is now out of support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Karl-Johan Sjögren. Just curious thou, this is the first time I deploy the project using docker and jenkins. So what is the 'runtime'? should I just go with FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:2.1 in my docker file?

Comment: A common way to setup your dockerfile is to use the sdk image to build your application but then when running you use another image with only the runtime as base. You can see an example of it on https://docs.docker.com/samples/dotnetcore/. Maybe you didn't have that in your dockerfile, if so you can just use the sdk and it will be fine as well.

Comment: Again thank you. but neither of both work.
it throws error saying && npm install && npm run build:dll && npm start' returned a non-zero code: 127. This is the part where RUN works in the file.

Comment: That is a separate problem. The old images probably had nodejs installed which the new ones seems to lack. You can either install node in the image yourself or use another image to build your frontend stuff. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918919/how-to-integrate-npm-install-into-asp-net-core-2-1-docker-build for more info on that.