# Docker file with asp.net throws npm not found error while it is building in Jenkins

Tags: asp.net, docker, jenkins, npm

I am trying to build docker file below through Jenkins.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:2.1 AS build

ARG PROFILE=Production

WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./

RUN cd src/stayfolio.Demo.Web.aroundfollie \
    && npm install && npm run build:dll && npm start

RUN dotnet restore stayfolio.Demo.Web.sln \
    && cd src/stayfolio.Demo.Web.aroundfollie \
    && mkdir -p build/outputs/aroundfollie \
    && dotnet publish --output ../../build/outputs/aroundfollie/

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:2.1

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/build/outputs/aroundfollie ./

CMD ["dotnet", "stayfolio.Demo.Web.aroundfollie.dll"]
```

However while building the file, it gives an error saying

> step 5/10 : RUN cd src/stayfolio.Demo.Web.aroundfollie     && npm install && npm run build:dll && npm start
> ---> Running in 86a2e1e8efcf
> [91m/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
> [0mThe command '/bin/sh -c cd src/stayfolio.Demo.Web.aroundfollie     && npm install && npm run build:dll && npm start' returned a non-zero code: 127

as you can see my docker file, I mentioned **&& npm install && npm run build:dll && npm start**, but why the error saying **npm: not found**?

Comment: Why do you expect to have `npm`? I think you need to install it.

Comment: npm is already installed. According to this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918919/how-to-integrate-npm-install-into-asp-net-core-2-1-docker-build, local installation does not help

Comment: If you're referring to accepted answer, you'll see that they're installing `nodejs` when building image: `RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential`. What do you mean by _local installing_? On machine or in image?

Comment: @StefanGolubović I think I got confused. So you are suggesting install npm using npm install in the project directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the docker image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk` does not have npm installed. You can install it with the package manager or copy it from another docker image.

Example:

```
FROM node:alpine AS node_base
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:2.1 AS build
COPY --from=node_base . .
# the rest of your Dockerfile
```

This approach is also described in the article you mentioned in your comment [How to integrate 'npm install' into ASP.NET CORE 2.1 Docker build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918919/how-to-integrate-npm-install-into-asp-net-core-2-1-docker-build)

Comment: From my side, it's throw the error:
[development 2/8] COPY --from=node_base . .:
------
cannot replace to directory /var/lib/docker/overlay2/mlj2yejxez6n1w4i9n9jlksqt/merged/usr/share/doc/perl-base with file